# How to code for Variable Length files in Micro Focus COBOL

Tags: cobol, mainframe

Facts:

1. Using VMWARE
2. Using Micro Focus COBOL
3. Must use Enterprise COBOL for z/OS compile dialect
4. Input is a variable length file
5. Getting various open errors

I can't seem to find the right combination of COBOL code to process the file.

From my program:

```
SELECT SYSUT1-FILE ASSIGN TO SYSUT1 ORGANIZATION IS SEQUENTIAL 
ACCESS MODE IS SEQUENTIAL FILE STATUS IS SYSUT1-STATUS. 

FD SYSUT1-FILE DATA RECORD IS SYSUT1-RECORD RECORDING MODE is V 
   RECORD IS VARYING IN SIZE from 1 to 256 DEPENDING ON WS-RECORD-SIZE. 
01 SYSUT1-RECORD PIC X(256).
```

DCB info for file: DS Org: PS Code Set: EBCDIC LRECL: 256 BLKSIZE: 00000 RECFM: VB

JCL:

```
// DLBL SYSUT1,'VDE.TAPE.PLUMW',0 
// DLBL SYSUT2,'TCP380.PLUMDATA',0 
// EXEC T3E2A380
```

Updated code:

```
   FD  SYSUT1-FILE
       BLOCK CONTAINS 00000
       DATA RECORD    IS SYSUT1-RECORD
       RECORDING MODE is V
       RECORD IS VARYING IN SIZE from 1 to 256
       DEPENDING ON WS-RECORD-SIZE.

   01  SYSUT1-RECORD                      PIC X(256).
```

When I used the above code, I got a File status 39 on the open.

Then I tired it using 252 bytes and got a File-Status-9/00041 (Corrupt index file) on the open.

Comment: Can you add the code you have tried to your question, and include the messages you are getting? Is VMWARE relevant, are you getting errors there?

Comment: I am executing the program within ESMAC(MICRO FOCUS) under VMWARE. That's where I am getting File open errors.

Comment: *MSG * T3E2A380 SYSUT1-Failure-OPEN... 
*MSG * T3E2A380 File-Status-39 
*MSG * T3E2A380 PROGRAM-IS-ABENDING...

Comment: Means nothing. You are getting a COBOL file status of 39. Which has a meaning (standard). Without seeing your code (SELECT, FD and OPEN) it will be difficult to correct your code. Also need to know about your file in the JCL.

Comment: I've updated my answer as far as possible without knowing more from you. It is nothing to do with VMWARE, so that tag can go.

Comment: Facts: 1) Impossible to debug code to see why it's not working if you don't post the code. 2) Impossible to debug errors when the errors are not described - "Getting various open errors" is meaningless unless you include information on what those *various errors* are, particularly when you don't include any code that we could use to figure that out. 3) If you have additional information about the problem, you need to [edit] your question to include that information there instead of burying it in comments where it can't be seen.

Comment: I've pasted your stuff from your comments for you. Seemed quicker than waiting.

Comment: And the update should do you now.

Comment: Checked your code now, updated my answer. Your code works with the 252 as expected. Your problem is now with your file/environment and you have to take that up with your Technical Support.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
FD  SYSUT1-FILE
    BLOCK CONTAINS 00000
    DATA RECORD    IS SYSUT1-RECORD
    RECORDING MODE is V
    RECORD IS VARYING IN SIZE from 1 to 252
    DEPENDING ON WS-RECORD-SIZE.

01  SYSUT1-RECORD                      PIC X(252).
```

I've just compiled and run a program with that in, reading a RECFM=VB, LRECL=256 dataset (you don't need so many zeros on the BLOCK CONTAINS, zero is zero, but it doesn't hurt).

However, I've not got access to z/VSE or to a Micro Focus Workbench emulating that OS.

You have a plain, flat, sequential file, so you can't have a corrupt index of that file.

You need to check your file now. Can you "look at" the content of that file in some way? Otherwise find a utility program, SORT for instance, and try to use that file as input.

If you get a failure, try with a different VB file (even if you have to make one) that you know has data on. If that works, try to create a new file for your program to use.

If you still get nowhere, it is one for your Technical Support people. They will contact Micro Focus if needed.

Your file definition (SELECT and FD) now work, I can OPEN, READ, and CLOSE in a COBOL program.

Your problem now is specific to the file (it may be corrupted, and although a real OS would know this, perhaps the Micro Focus emulation doesn't) or there is some wider problem with your environment.

Running z/VSE under Micro Focus emulation will be quite rare these days. I don't think you'll get much more from SO.

---

First thing from your latest information is that you are not using z/OS, at least not when you are running your program. That is `DOS` JCL, so the target OS is likely to be z/VSE. Shouldn't matter, probably, just came as a surprise. Don't see much DOS JCL these days.

As already mentioned, it is now simple. You dataset is VB, your LRECL is 256 (which is the four-byte RDW plue 252 bytes of data) and you have defined 256 bytes of data in the 01 under your FD. Change that to 252.

Here is what IBM's Enterprise COBOL thinks of File Status 39 (will be the same for COBOL running under z/VSE):

---

> The OPEN statement was unsuccessful because a conflict was
>   detected between the fixed file attributes and the
>   attributes specified for that file in the program. These
>   attributes include the organization of the file
>   (sequential, relative, or indexed), the prime record key, the
>   alternate record keys, the code set, the maximum record size,
>   the record type (fixed or variable), and the blocking
>   factor.

The description of your actual file in Micro Focus's JCL does not match the description of the file in your program. The message covers a wide variety of situations, and only knowing what is in your code and how the actual file is defined can lead to a resolution.

The most likely thing is "one file is fixed-length records, the other is variable-length records" or "one file thinks the maximum length is X whereas the other thinks it is Y".

For the maximum length of a record, remember, as you should already have read below, the COBOL program should define as a maximum the length of the data-part only (excluding the RDW), but the JCL must define the maximum length *including* the RDW. Ie the maxima should be different by four bytes. If the LRECL is not explicit in the JCL, it is obtained from the catalog entry for the dataset.

You should have some way within your "workbench" to determine the characteristics of a file, and ensure that they match to the definition in the program (remembering not to include the RDW in the program).

There are three ways to indicate to COBOL that you have a file of variable-length records. All presume that you specify a `RECORDING MODE V` in the `FD`, but that is not enough.

If the file contains multiple record-layouts with at least one being of different length from the others, then simply defining the records under the FD will tell COBOL that your file contains variable-length records.

```
FD ....
01  RECORD-1 PIC X.
02  RECORD-2 PIC XX.
```

On an IBM Mainframe, each variable-length record is preceded by a Record Descriptor Word (RDW). That, being an implementation detail (how it is achieve is not dictated in the COBOL Standard), is not included in the record-layout. Your actual file will have an LRECL (Logical Record Length) which *does* include the length of the RDW (the W means Word which means four bytes).

In the above example, the LRECL may be 6 (RDW + the maximum possible record-length).

If your file contains a single record-type, but that record may be of different lengths due to the number of items included in an OCCURS, then simply including the record-layout with an `OCCURS ... DEPENDING ON` will be enough.

```
FD ....
01  RECORD-1.
    05  SOME-FIXED-LENGTH-DATA PIC X(200).
    05  NUMBER-OF-ITEMS BINARY PIC 9(4).
    05  FILLER 
        OCCURS 1 TO 10 TIMES
        DEPENDING ON NUMBER-OF-ITEMS.
        10  FIXED-DATA-IN-VARIABLE-AMOUNTS PIC X(10).
```

If your records are of no particular fixed structure (text, XML, whatever) then you need this.

```
FD  ... RECORD IS VARYING FROM minimum-length TO maximum-length
        DEPENDING ON NUMBER-OF-BYTES-OF-DATA.
01  RECORD-1                     PIC X(maximum-length).
...
WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
01  NUMBER-OF-BYTES-OF-DATA BINARY PIC 9(4).
```

minimum-length and maximum-length are actual numbers for your data.

When you `READ` that file, the field NUMBER-OF-BYTES-OF-DATA will receive the count of the number of bytes of data in the record (excluding the RDW).

When you want to `WRITE` a record, you set NUMBER-OF-BYTES-OF-DATA to the number of data bytes you have before the WRITE, and everything goes smoothly (NUMBER-OF-BYTES-OF-DATA is just an example name, make yours relevant to the file).

Comment: I am executing the program under JCL Control (Micro Focus) within a virtual machine (VMWARE).

Comment: @vealparm ? Edit your question to include additional information, as has already been requested, please.

Comment: From my program:

SELECT SYSUT1-FILE  ASSIGN TO SYSUT1
ORGANIZATION IS SEQUENTIAL
ACCESS MODE  IS SEQUENTIAL
FILE STATUS  IS SYSUT1-STATUS.
--------

FD  SYSUT1-FILE
DATA RECORD    IS SYSUT1-RECORD
RECORDING MODE is V
RECORD IS VARYING IN SIZE from 1 to 256
DEPENDING ON WS-RECORD-SIZE.
01  SYSUT1-RECORD                      PIC X(256).
--------

DCB info for file:

DS Org: PS
Code Set: EBCDIC
LRECL: 256
BLKSIZE: 00000
RECFM: VB

Comment: I don't know hot to include carriage returns in the comments.

Comment: // DLBL SYSUT1,'VDE.TAPE.PLUMW',0
// DLBL SYSUT2,'TCP380.PLUMDATA',0
// EXEC T3E2A380

Comment: Thanks for continued help. I changed to 252 and got the same open error. Any other suggestions?

Comment: You changed the 1 TO 256 *and* the PIC X(256)?

Comment: I changed both to 252. Didn't work. Then tried changing one to 252, leaving the other at 256, then the opposite. None of the combos worked.

Comment: OK. Put both to 252. You show Blocksize of 00000. That is *probably* using a default blocksize from the system. You have no `BLOCK CONTAINS` at all in your FD, and the default is one record per block. Code `BLOCK CONTAINS 0` in your FD. If that does not work, paste exactly what you have currently for your FD and 01 into your question using the edit link under your question.